# Fourier transform of $f(x) = [-i(x+i\epsilon)]^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-transform

Let $\epsilon>0$ be a positive infinitesimal constant. What is the Fourier transform of $f(x) = [-i(x+i\epsilon)]^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha>0$ (we always consider the principal branch); in other words, what is
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-ikx} dx?$$
The integral is understood as the improper Riemann integral. Mathematica says that the answer is
$$\frac{2\pi}{\Gamma(\alpha)} k^{\alpha-1} \theta(k),$$
where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function and $\theta$ is the Heaviside function. How can I obtain this analytically?

Note: (1) The integral is easily seen to be zero for $k<0$, by using the residue theorem; closing the contour on the upper half plane, the function $f$ does not have any poles or branch cuts.
(2) If $\alpha$ is an integer, then the result for $k>0$ is again obtained from the residue theorem. For fractional $\alpha$, due to the branch cut of $f$ on the lower half plane, the residue theorem is not straightforward.

Comment: There is a branch point at $-i\varepsilon$.  How are you defining $f$?

Comment: Mathematica tells me the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}_x\left[(-i x)^{-\alpha }\right](k)=\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty } (-i x)^{-\alpha}\, e^{-i k x} \, dx=\frac{2 \pi k^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma (\alpha )}$ (assuming $k>0$) is only valid for $0<\Re(\alpha)<1$.

Comment: A very similar integral is in here somewhere: https://open.library.ubc.ca/soa/cIRcle/collections/ubctheses/24/items/1.0402359

Basically you use a square contour and you can determine it's either zero or an exponential depending on the sign. There's a math stack exchange question about this integral somewhere too.

Comment: @StevenClark The Fourier Transform exists as a distribution for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(z)=\frac1{(-i(z+i\varepsilon))^\alpha}$, with $\alpha>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$, is multivalued with a branch point at $z=-i\alpha$.

We choose to cut the plane from $z=-i\alpha$ along a ray on the imaginary axis.  Then, for $k>0$, we close the contour in the upper-half plane and find that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-ikx}}{(-i(x+i\varepsilon))^\alpha}\,dx=0\tag1$$

For $k<0$, we close the contour in the lower-half plane, deforming around the branch cut and find that for $\nu>0$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-ikx}}{(-i(x+i\varepsilon))^\alpha}\,dx=2\sin(\alpha \pi)e^{-ik\varepsilon}\int_{\nu}^\infty \frac{e^{-kt}}{t^\alpha}\,dy-e^{-k\varepsilon}\nu^{1-\alpha}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\nu ke^{i\phi}}e^{i(1-\alpha)\phi}\,d\phi\tag2$$

Next, we let $\nu\to 0$.  To do this, we repeatedly integrate by parts ($\lfloor \alpha \rfloor$ times) the first integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$.  This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Sorry for a delayed response. I have a question on Eq. (2).

First, why one introduces $\nu>0$? What is the meaning of this parameter?
Second, I think the first term in the RHS of (2) is $2\sin(\alpha \pi) e^{-ik\epsilon} \int_\nu^\infty \frac{e^{-kt}}{t^\alpha} dt $. I think the substitution $ix=t$ is made. 
Third, I cannot see how the last term in the RHS of (2) arises, and what $\phi$ means.

Comment: Good questions.  There is a branch point at $z=-i\varepsilon$.  We need to deform the contour around the branch point.  We do so with a circular contour of radius $\nu<\varepsilon$.   So the deformed contour is comprised of rays from $(1)$ $-i(\nu+\varepsilon)$ to $-i\infty$ to the right of the branch cut, $(2)$ $-i\infty$ to $-i(\nu+\varepsilon)$ to the left of the branch cut, and $(3)$ a circular contour with center at $-i\varepsilon$ and radius $\nu$ around the branch point.